# org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Exception while setting value

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am getting above error when i am trying to get the results in DTO type List from Solr.

I have the below bean class

```
@Field("email_address")
private String email_address;

@Field("bean_module")
private String bean_module;

@Field("previous_status")
private List<String> previous_status;
```

And I try to get the results from Solr using the below code:

```
SolrQuery params = new SolrQuery();
QueryResponse response = SOLRCORE.query(params);
SolrDocumentList productDocumentList = response.getResults();
DocumentObjectBinder binder = new DocumentObjectBinder();
List<LeadDTO>  arrayList = binder.getBeans(LeadDTO.class,productDocumentList);
```

the above code throws the below Exception.

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Could not instantiate object of class com.kaldin.dto.LeadDTO
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBean(DocumentObjectBinder.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBeans(DocumentObjectBinder.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse.getBeans(QueryResponse.java:618)
    at com.kaldin.dao.SolarDao.getSearchResult(SolarDao.java:193)
    at com.kaldin.dao.SolarDao.main(SolarDao.java:452)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Exception while setting value : [pleaseverify@email.com] on private java.lang.String com.kaldin.dto.LeadDTO.email_address
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.set(DocumentObjectBinder.java:455)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.inject(DocumentObjectBinder.java:438)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBean(DocumentObjectBinder.java:67)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.kaldin.dto.LeadDTO.email_address to java.util.ArrayList
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.set(DocumentObjectBinder.java:449)
```

below are the fields we added in Solr

```
<field name="email_address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bean_module" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="previous_status" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I did a lot of search on google as well as checked the same question on StackOverflow and tired but I am still persisted the same issue

Comment: I suspect from the error is you email address field is also multivalued in Solr, but you are defining it as string so in logs it's complaining about can't bind because of datatype mismatch

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Exception while setting value : [pleaseverify@email.com] on private java.lang.String com.kaldin.dto.LeadDTO.email_address arraylist to string can't map

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same exception. I added `multiValued = "false"` and it worked for me. As logs tells that `ArrayList` is going to be assigned to `String`, it is not possible.

> Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Exception while setting value : [pleaseverify@email.com] on private java.lang.String

and `email_address` in you DTO is string

```
@Field("email_address")
private String email_address;
```

I hope when you use `multiValued="false"` like this it will work.

```
<field name="email_address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```